# AuthorizeAttribute not recognizing AuthCookie in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

Upon successful Login I have this line

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(a.username, true);
```

Then I have several pages which require login to be accessed, so I added the [Authorize] attribute to them like so

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
    return View();
}
```

However, after logging in, such functions still return a 401 - Unauthorized error page just as if the user had not logged in. The error page states:
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Furthermore, in my project Anonymous Authentication is enabled and Windows Authentication is disabled.

I am looking for a solution where funcitons like Upload() are always available to any logged in user.

Comment: Forms authentication needs to be enabled, look in your web.config if you have `<authentication mode="Forms">` in system.web

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Forms authentication needs to be enabled, look in your web.config if you have  in system.web" – glacasa

Answer (score 0):

What you can do and what I've done is to write your own cookie this way:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
     FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version number of ticket
     userName, // UserName
     DateTime.Now,             //cookie creation time
     DateTime.Now.AddHours(24), //Expiration time . cookie valid for 1 day
     true,  //Persistent
     userData); // other data to store in ticket
```

// set Cookie

```
Response.SetCookie(
            new HttpCookie(
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket)) //// encrypt ticket
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL
            });
```